# getting first answer as undefined in json responce

Tags: javascript, html, json

i dont know why the first value is undefined ,and only getting result without json.parse()  and 
the script and html is actually on the same page,
in php i just encode data into json and echo it,
,(dont mind this line)some one help me with stackoverflow is not letting me to post without larger question how to post question with a single line

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript">
         
         
        
         $(document).ready(function() {
          $("button").click(function(){
       
          $.ajax({
            // async: false,
            //dataType: "JSON",
          url: "ing.php",
          type: "POST",
          
        
        
          success: function(data)
          {
            var res;
            // var j=JSON.parse(data);
            for(x in data)
            {
            res += "<div>"+ data[x].id + "</div>"
            res += "<div>"+ data[x].number + "</div>";
          }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=res;
          }
          })
        });
        });
        
        </script>




      well this is what iam actually doing 
    iam getting but it seams not the proper one
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
         <title></title>

        </head>
        <body>
        
        <button >get data</button>
        
        <span id="result">r1
        </span>
    <!-- this is what iam actually getting
    undefined
    1
    31232 -->
        
        
        
        
     
        </body>
        </html>


    <?php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test"); ?>

    <?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM test where id='1'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $data[]=$row;      
    //result is [{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"31232","number":"31232","2":"sdasd","text":"sdasd"}]

    }

    $d=json_encode($data);
    echo $d;

    ?>
```

Comment: Which value do you post without write a data value?

Comment: @ Simone Rossaini actually i dont want to send anything to php, just get a  response from php (encoded json)

Comment: @ Simone Rossaini check the post again i didnt notice it incomplete now u can see javascript ,html,php the stackoverflow is new for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: please get your code in order - its impossible to see anything there.
The actual error is your `var res;` - you define res as undefined, so this is whats there first. you should use `var res = ''`!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var data = [{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"31232","number":"31232","2":"sdasd","text":"sdasd"}];
    
    // res is undefined! - should be:
    // var res = "";
    var res;
    for (x in data) {
      res += "<div>" + data[x].id + "</div>"
      res += "<div>" + data[x].number + "</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    well this is what iam actually doing iam getting but it seems not the proper one
    <button>get data</button><br />
    <span id="result">r1</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @ZPIDER it's right and i sure get the coding in order next time

Answer (score 0):

> Try Like this

```
$.ajax({         
      url: "ing.php",
      type: "POST",          
      success: function(data){
        var res;
        // var j=JSON.parse(data);
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        for(x in obj){
          res += "<div>"+ obj[x].id + "</div><div>"+ obj[x].number + "</div>";

        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=res;
        }
      });
```